# Strange inner view in SwiftUI buttons on Watch

Tags: swiftui, watchos-6

I am just starting out with both Watch development and SwiftUI, and thought I would start with a simple Login Screen. I have made two buttons of two different styles. The strange thing is that my buttons have a strange red inner view to them and I am not sure why.

```
struct ContentView : View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Button( "Login")
            {            
            }
            .accentColor( .white)
            .frame( idealHeight:50.0)
            .padding( [.leading, .trailing], 10.0)
            .background( Color.red)
            .cornerRadius( 5.0)

            Button( "Sign Up")
            {
            }
            .accentColor( .red)
            .frame( idealHeight:50.0)
            .padding( [.leading, .trailing], 10.0)
            .background( Color.white)
            .cornerRadius( 5.0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Watch Simulator]

Can someone tell me what is going on here ?

Also if someone has reputation of 1500 can they please create WatchOS6 tag ?

Update: This works way better on the iPhone than the Watch, Buttons seem to work differently on the two devices. As pointed out by @MarkT you need to start out with a button style of plain. The issue with this is that it stops you using your own Button Styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are only defining a background behind a "default" Button that's why it looks so wired.

Changing the button style to "plain" and apply the corner radius to the background will help. Of course you must adjust the background size by using padding to frame ...

```
       Button( "Login")
            {
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .padding(.horizontal, 60)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(
                   Color.red
                      .cornerRadius( 5.0))
```

Update: As mentioned from d4Rk we have to use PlainButtonStyle()

Comment: Good shout. I knew my answer was confused in some way.

Comment: This doesn't work, using your code above gives me a small rounded white square in a large rounded red button.

Comment: If you move .buttonStyle(.plain) to the first line (above .padding(.horizontal, 60) then it works!! Can you edit your answer and I will accept it.
Unfortunately it doesn't work with my ButtonStyles I had created so I will have to remove my own styles for now.

Comment: For me it was working but of corse I can move the buttonStyle to the first line. It should not make any difference.

Comment: Were you running it on the Watch ?  I just tried it on the iPhone and it behaved differently.  Have accepted your answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried it only in the Preview but I am happy that it’s working for you.

Comment: When I try doing it this way over here on Xcode 11.3.1 I get an error on the Button line: `Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'ButtonStyle' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`

Comment: `.plain` is deprecated, use `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())`  now.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
HStack {
        Button("Login")
            {
            }
        .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle(tint: .clear))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(5)
```

[image]

if its in a list try this as well

```
.listRowPlatterColor(Color.clear)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a result of using `accentColor` to define the colour of you text for the button.

You can substitute this for `foregroundColor` and achieve the same text colour but hopefully without the odd patterning you are currently experiencing.

With the changes your code would look like:

```
struct ContentView : View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Button( "Login")
            {            
            }
            .foregroundColor( .white)
            .frame( idealHeight:50.0)
            .padding( [.leading, .trailing], 10.0)
            .background( Color.red)
            .cornerRadius( 5.0)

            Button( "Sign Up")
            {
            }
            .foregroundColor( .red)
            .frame( idealHeight:50.0)
            .padding( [.leading, .trailing], 10.0)
            .background( Color.white)
            .cornerRadius( 5.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't entirely solve the issue.
As you can see we go from this:

[image: Inner background before]

to this:

[image: Inner background after]

Which is not ideal.

Comment: That is better, but not perfect, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/elements/buttons/) you should set the radius to 22 points (or 9 for scroll view)